# converting time in seconds to HH:MM:SS:FF

Tags: javascript, time, date-format, datetime-format, time-format

I am using video player in my ReactJs project.

I get the current time of the player in seconds and I want to convert that time into the [**HH:MM:SS:FF format**](http://www2.d125.org/applied_arts/teched/courses/AV/files/timecode.pdf), where the `FF` represents a particular frame.

I'm already able to convert a time into the `HH:MM:SS` format, like this:

```
secondsToHms = (d) => {
  d = Number(d);
  var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
  var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
  return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "00" : "") : "00:") + "0"+ m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
}
```

Assuming that I have a video that plays at a framerate of 24 frames per second and I'm getting my time eg. like `126.2344452`, how can I improve my function to also calculate the `FF` part?

Comment: Are you asking us how to concatenate a number to that string ? Or what ?

Comment: I am asking how to convert the 126.4231434 sec to hh:mm:ss:ff

Comment: I get the time output in seconds format. I could find a solution for converting it to hh:mm:ss but not to hh:mm:ss:ff

Comment: That depends on fps whats your video frame per second it ranges from 24 to 30 which can be calculated by remaining seconds

Comment: I mentioned in ques. Assume that I have 24 fps video.

Comment: I can't find a dup, and it is hardly too board, and too simple is not a reason to close it, so I actually ended up thinking it may deserves an answer.

Comment: @ApurvG : Sheepy's answer does not produce the correct results. My answer should give you exactly what you're looking for ;-)

Comment: @JohnSlegers Yes I remembered the number base wrong which is kind of embarrassing considering the hours I have spend on editing videos.  I have corrected my answer to zero base.

Comment: @Sheepy : You might want to remove the comment as well + add some padding for values 0 to 9 ;-)

Comment: @Sheepy : A quick comparison between the output of both answers, in their current form : https://jsfiddle.net/1xf26snv/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the `FF`, just (1) multiply your total number of seconds by the framerate and (2) do a [modulo division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) :

```
numberofseconds * fps % fps
```

This is a variation on your function that converts to `HH:MM:SS:FF` correctly :

```
var convertTime = function (input, fps) {
    var pad = function(input) {return (input < 10) ? "0" + input : input;};
    fps = (typeof fps !== 'undefined' ?  fps : 24 );
    return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input * fps % fps))
    ].join(':');
}
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var convertTime = function (input, fps) {
    var pad = function(input) {return (input < 10) ? "0" + input : input;};
    fps = (typeof fps !== 'undefined' ?  fps : 24 );
    return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input * fps % fps))
    ].join(':');
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify({
    5.4416555 : convertTime(5.4416555),
    126.2344452 : convertTime(126.2344452),
    1156.1535548 : convertTime(1156.1535548),
    9178.1351559 : convertTime(9178.1351559),
    13555.3515135 : convertTime(13555.3515135)
}, null, '\t') +  '</pre>';
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1xf26snv/10/).

Comment: Thanks John. It worked.

Comment: The other solution provide by Sheepy also works

Comment: @ApurvG : My solution always provides 2 digits at the end. Sheepy's solution (the current version) produces the same output, except it provides only one digit at the end when the frame is between 0 and 9!

Comment: @ApurvG : A quick comparison between the output of my solution & Sheepy's solution : https://jsfiddle.net/1xf26snv/11/

Comment: Yes. That's why I marked your's correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the fps, the calculation should be pretty straight forward:

1. Get the decimal part of the time with `second % 1`.
2. Multiply it by fps: 0.0 second is "frame 0", and 0.9999 second is "frame fps-1".
3. Frame count is generally zero based, but you can add 1 to make it 1 based.

If you want the total frame instead, simply skip step 1.

```
secondsToHms = ( d, fps = 24 ) => {
   const pad2 = txt => ( '0' + Math.floor( txt ) ).substr( -2 ),
         h = pad2( d / 3600 ),
         m = pad2( d % 3600 / 60 ),
         s = pad2( d % 60 ),
         f = pad2( d % 1 * fps ); // +1 here for one based frame
   return `${h}:${m}:${s}:${f}`;
}
```

> I have taken the liberty to refactor your function.  I hope it is still recognisably yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ll try it and let you know if any problem accurs.

Comment: This solution also workds

Comment: @JohnSlegers Frame rate is not limited to 60 like minutes or seconds: 120fps is not that rare nowadays.  But if you want the frames to be always at least two digits, it's a simple replace of the methods, as shown in an update of the answer despite that I assumed you should be able to adjust yourself as a fellow programmer.